# How do I change the File Version of a Microsoft Visual C++ EXE or DLL?

Tags: visual-c++, versioning

I've been tasked with updating one of our old programs still in production and don't know my way around MS Visual C++ 6.0. How do I update the File Version as reported in the Windows Explorer File Properties dialog?

Comment: Hi.  I mean the version of the exe or dll that gets generated from the c++ source code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the File Version as reported by File / Properties in Windows explorer?  Look for the `VERSION` resource in the Resource View.